# How do I enable a button while in read-only mode in DHTMLX Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using a `dhtmlx` scheduler in my MVC application.

I have added a custom button which is simply a link to an action. The button works perfectly when not in read-only mode. My issue is that this button should be used while the lightbox is in read-only mode and for some reason the button seems to be disabled while in this mode. The button shows up, but does not link me to where I need to go.

**Edit:**

How I added the custom button:

```
scheduler.config.buttons_right = ["dhx_delete_btn", "enroll_button"];
scheduler.locale.labels["enroll_button"] = "Enroll";
```

My Event for the button:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onClick", function(id, e1){
    scheduler.attachEvent("onLightboxButton", function(button_id, node, e){
        if(button_id == "enroll_button"){
            window.location = "/Calendar/Enroll?id="+id;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You'll need to add some code

Comment: @Mick What would you like to see? Are you familiar with DHTMLX Scheduler?